# How to shade the area under a curve ok Kaplan-Meier (step function)

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, survival

I like to obtain graphically the area under a curve de Kaplan-Meier.
I have done the previous recommendation in this stack overflow but it doesn't work correctly

Example

```
library(survival)
data (cancer)
veteran 

km <- survfit(Surv(time,status)~1, data=leukemia)
plot(km, conf.int=F, xlab="time until relapse (in weeks)", mark.time = T,
     ylab="proportion without relapse",lab=c(10,10,7),col='blue')
abline(h=0)
abline(v=0)

time <- km$time[km$time <= 30]
surv <- km$surv[km$time <= 30]
polygon(
  c(min(time), time, max(time)),
  c(0, surv, 0),
  col = "blue", border = F
)

library(ggplot2)
dat <- data.frame(
  time = km$time,
  surv = km$surv
)
ggplot(dat, aes(time, surv)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 40, color = "blue") +
  geom_area(data = subset(dat, time <= 40), fill = "blue") +
  theme_minimal()
```

I would like to obtain graphically the area under curve between 0 and 40,   AND  between 20 and 60.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
library(survival)
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)
library(zoo) 

km <- survfit(Surv(time,status)~1, data=leukemia)
plot(km, conf.int=F, xlab="time until relapse (in weeks)", mark.time = T,
     ylab="proportion without relapse",lab=c(10,10,7),col='blue')
abline(h=0)
abline(v=0)


fill_data=function(this_km){
  out=rbind(data.table(time=0,surv=1),data.table(time=this_km$time,surv=this_km$surv))
  out=rbind(na.omit(out[,.(time,surv=shift(surv))]),out)
  setkeyv(out,"time")
  return(out)
}

data=fill_data(km)
data[,surv:=na.locf(surv)]

ggplot()+
  geom_step(aes(time,surv), col='blue', lwd=1.5, data=data) + 
  geom_area(data=data, aes(x=time,y=surv), fill='pink', alpha=1, lwd=0.1)  +
  labs(x = "Time (months)", y = "Survival", title = "")+
  theme_classic() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(from= 0, to=160, by = 10))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(from= 0, to=1, by = 0.2))+
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0) +
  theme(legend.position = c(0.8, 0.8), legend.direction = "vertical", 
        legend.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
        legend.title = element_text(family = "Courier", color = "black", size = 14,  face = 1), 
        legend.text = element_text (size = 20)) + 
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 14))+
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 18)) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = 14)),
        axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(r = 14))) +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank(), legend.key.height = unit(2, "lines"))

summary(km)
summary(km, times = c(20,60))
fix(data) # time 20 - surv 0.646, time 60  surv 0.0828

data4 = subset(data, time >= 20 & time <= 60)
ggplot()+
  geom_step(aes(time,surv), col='blue', lwd=1, data=data) + 
  geom_area(data=data4, aes(x=time,y=surv), fill='pink', alpha=0.5, lwd=0.75)  +
  labs(x = "Time (months)", y = "Survival", title = "")+
  theme_classic() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(from= 0, to=160, by = 10))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(from= 0, to=1, by = 0.2))
```

[image]

[image]

Thanks ¡¡¡

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your data lacks the exact time points. Hence, to achieve your desired result you need an estimate or prediction for these time points. As your KM curve is piecewise-linear you could use linear interpolation e.g. using `approx()`:

```r
library(survival)
data(cancer)

km <- survfit(Surv(time, status) ~ 1, data = leukemia)

library(ggplot2)

km1 <- approx(km$time, km$surv, c(km$time, 40, 20, 60))

dat <- data.frame(
  time = km1$x,
  surv = km1$y
)

ggplot(dat, aes(time, surv)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 40, color = "blue") +
  geom_area(data = subset(dat, time <= 40), fill = "blue", alpha = .5) +
  geom_area(data = subset(dat, time >= 20 & time <= 60), fill = "green", alpha = .5) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But again, when you represent the curve as (geom_step) there is a "gap" between the curve and the area, as in the previous middle figure

Comment: ggplot(dat, aes(time, surv)) +
  geom_step() +
  geom_area(data = subset(dat, time <= 40), fill = "blue", alpha = .5) +
  theme_minimal()